# Inverse Laplace by phase shifting

Tags: laplace-transform

Can anyone help me out here?

I have to find the inverse laplace of

$$ \frac{s (1-e^{-s/2})}{s^2+\pi^2}$$

Sorry it looks bad, I just don't know how to format. Here's the wolframalpha link:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+of+%28s%281-e%5E%28-s%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28s%5E2+%2Bpi%5E2%29+

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3):

$$\hat{f}(s) = \frac{s (1-e^{-s/2})}{s^2+\pi^2} e^{s t} = \frac{s }{s^2+\pi^2} e^{s t} - \frac{s\, e^{-s/2}}{s^2+\pi^2} e^{s t} $$

and sum them up.  For the first piece, from a complex analysis standpoint, you just need to evaluate the residues at the poles $s_{\pm} = \pm i \pi$ of the function  This sum of residues is

$$f_1(t) = \frac{i \pi }{2 i \pi} e^{i \pi t} + \frac{-i \pi }{-2 i \pi} e^{-i \pi t} $$

Simplifying, we get

$$f_1(t) = \cos{\pi t}$$

For the second piece, rewrite as

$$\frac{s\, e^{-s/2}}{s^2+\pi^2} e^{s t} = \frac{s }{s^2+\pi^2} e^{s (t-1/2)} $$

Note that when $t< 1/2$, the (Bromwich) integration contour must go to the right of the line $\Re{z}=c$ in order to converge.  Because there are no poles within that contour, the ILT $f(t)$ is zero here.  For $t \ge 1/2$, however, we may use the normal contour to the left of $\Re{z}=c$ and sum the residues at $s_{\pm} = \pm i \pi$:

$$f_2(t) = \frac{i \pi e^{-i \pi/2} }{2 i \pi} e^{i \pi t} + \frac{-i \pi e^{i \pi/2} }{-2 i \pi} e^{-i \pi t} = -\sin{\pi t}$$

Therefore, the ILT is

$$f(t) = \cos{\pi t} - H\left( t-\frac12 \right) \sin{\pi t}$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: I thought you're gone. Glad you keep your neat point of view, Ron. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: you are too kind.  I had made a major error (was up too late last night), and I needed to remove it until it was fixed.

Comment: @RonGordon Hi how do you know that append the heaviside step function at the end? It is not apparent from the method of residue. This is related to my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941710/what-is-the-reason-for-failure-of-residue-method-for-inversion-of-laplace-transf

Answer (score 3):

If we set:
$$F(s) = \frac{s (1-e^{-s/2})}{s^2+\pi^2}$$ so you have $$F(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+\pi^2}-\frac{s e^{-s/2}}{s^2+\pi^2}$$ Now use the followings to get the answer:

$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\cos(ax),~~\text{e}^{-as}\mathcal{L}f(t)=\mathcal{L}(u_a(t)f(t-a))$$

In fact, $$\frac{s e^{-s/2}}{s^2+\pi^2}=\text{e}^{\frac{-1}{2}s}\frac{s }{s^2+\pi^2}=\text{e}^{\frac{-1}{2}s}\mathcal{L}(\cos\pi t)=\mathcal{L}\left(u_{\left(\frac{-1}2\right)}(t)\cos\pi(t-1/2)\right)$$

Comment: Which is the f(t) function?

Comment: @Ramon: $f(t)=\cos\pi t$.

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding it. I'm going all over the place and don't have the correct answer.
Mind finishing problem? 

I'll set up another so I can workthrough

Comment: Really nice work, here, Babak ;-)