# What is the reason for failure of residue method for inversion of laplace transform $F(s) = \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s-8}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, residue-calculus, partial-fractions

Let $F(s) = \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s-8}$

Using the **residue method**, we find that the residue at pole $s = 8$ for the function $F(s)e^{st}$ to be $e^{-8}e^{8t} =e^{8(t-1)} $

Since $f(t) = \sum\limits_k \text{Res}\{F(s)e^{st};p_k\}$ (see reference)

This means $f(t) = e^{8(t-1)}$

**However, this is wrong**. The correct answer is  $f(t) = e^{8(t-1)}u(t-1)$, where $u$ is the heaviside/unit step function

How can I take into account of the unit step using the residue method?

---

Reference: 1. http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~george1/laplace_residue.pdf
[image]

Similar problem: [Inverse Laplace transformation using reside method of transfer function that contains time delay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403042/inverse-laplace-transformation-using-reside-method-of-transfer-function-that-con)

Comment: Check the definition of the inverse LT at the bottom of page $1$
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2 \pi j} \int_{\sigma - j \infty}^{\sigma + j \infty} F(s) e^{st} ds &\mbox{if } t \ge 0 \\
0 &\mbox{if } t \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

Can you see what you haven't taken into account? (Look at example 1, page 3)

Comment: @Mattos I see, then this formula can be adjusted to deal with cases where you have the negative exponential on the numerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-st}dt$ converges for $Re(s) > \sigma_0$ with $f(t) e^{-\sigma_0 t} \in L^1$, then (by the Fourier inversion theorem) it is always true that for $\sigma > \sigma_0$ : $$f(t) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds$$

Now you should look at the proof of $$\int_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds = 2i \pi \sum_\rho Res(F(s)e^{st},\rho) \tag{1}$$

It assumes that **$F(s)e^{st}$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) \ge \sigma$ (always the case if $\sigma > \sigma_0$), and  meromorphic on the rest of the complex plane.**

It also requires that $F(s) e^{st} \to 0$ fast enough as $|Im(s)|  \to \infty$ so that (by the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) following from the [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem))
$$\int_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}+\int_{\eta+i \infty}^{\eta-i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds = 2i \pi \sum_{Re(\rho) \in (\eta,\sigma)} Res(F(s)e^{st},\rho)$$

Now if $F(s) e^{st} \to 0$ fast enough as $Re(s) \to -\infty$, you have $\lim_{\eta \to - \infty} \int_{\eta+i \infty}^{\eta-i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds = 0$ and $(1)$ follows.

But in general this is true  only for $t$ sufficiently large, namely $t > t_0$. For $t<t_0$, it is the opposite : if  $F(s)e^{st} \to 0$ (fast enough) as $Re(s) \to +\infty$, you get that :

$$\int_{\sigma-i \infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds = \lim_{\eta \to +\infty}\int_{\eta-i \infty}^{\eta+i\infty} F(s) e^{st}ds = 0$$

Comment: Hi, can you comment on why this particular case in my original post doesn't work?

Comment: @BeachedWhale well I tried to explain what you need for proving and understanding it : find for which $t$ you have $F(s) e^{st} \to 0$ as $Re(s) \to - \infty$ or $F(s) e^{st} \to 0$ as $Re(s) \to + \infty$

Comment: Hi can you comment the specific place for which the residue method fails to work for $F(s)  = \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s-8}$

Comment: @BeachedWhale I told you it doesn't fail, and that you have to understand where it comes from (the limit $\eta\to -\infty$ ...)

Comment: Can you explicitly show how this works for this example? You have said that this works for a threshold of $t > t_0$, but what is $t_0$? I will accept your answer immediately if you can show how the inversion can be performed correctly

Comment: @BeachedWhale you don't see that $\frac{e^{-s}}{s-8}e^{st}$ doesn't $\to 0$ as $Re(s) \to - \infty$ when $t$ is too small ?

Comment: @BeachedWhale and if you accept an answer without understand it I don't see the point. Here you have to get that we are looking at a limit $\eta \to - \infty$ working only for $t$ large enough. For $t$ small, we look instead at $\eta \to + \infty$